# Trying to convert str to datetime with strptime and getting error

Tags: python, datetime

For some reason strptime function produces error but I don't know why

Initially what I wanted to do looked like

```
test = datetime.datetime.strptime('12/16/2019 0:00', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M')
```

But after getting errors, i also tried other formats and still the same

```
test = datetime.datetime.strptime('12/16/2019 00:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
```

the error is

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pavlo/PycharmProjects/test/test2.py", line 22, in 
    test = datetime.datetime.strptime('12/16/2019 00:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
  File "C:\Users\pavlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Users\pavlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '12/16/2019 00:00' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'

Comment: You asked it to to use the format day/month/4 digit year hours:minutes but clearly you are passing month/day/year Hour,minute... 12/16/2019 ... 16th month can't be found and hence the value error. The following in quotes should work .. "test = datetime.datetime.strptime('12/16/2019 00:00', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')" .. I suggest you to read more about datetime module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should revert the order of day and month, %d/%m/ to %m/%d/ or 12/16 to 16/12